# updating Hierarchy Level

Tags: sqlite, recursion, updates, hierarchy

We have a single table that includes Parent/Child relationships.
We are trying to update the Level of the Children based on the Parents Level + 1
We are currently doing a loop in code that looks something like this:

```
Dim ParentLevel as Integer = 1

Do While Count > 0

Update [MyTable]
SET [MyLevel] = (SELECT [P].[MyLevel] + 1
                 FROM [MyTable] [P]
                 WHERE [MyTable].[Parent] = [P].[Child]
                   AND [P].[MyLevel] = ParentLevel)
WHERE [MyLevel] IS NULL
  AND [Parent] IN (SELECT [Child]
                   FROM [MyTable] [P]
                   WHERE P.[MyLevel] = ParentLevel);

execute query

ParentLevel = ParentLevel + 1

Loop
```

This table has only 31148 records.
When ParentLevel is below around 3 or 4 the update query's performance is acceptable.
However after that it takes to long. Therefore we know we must be doing some wrong.

Indexes are on parent and Child and MyLevel.

We've tried other update queries like below but performance is the same:

```
Update [MyTable]
SET [MyLevel] = (SELECT P.[MyLevel] + 1
                 FROM [MyTable] AS P
                 WHERE [MyTable].[Parent] = P.[Child]
                   AND [P].[MyLevel] = ParentLevel )
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT P.[MyLevel] + 1
              FROM [MyTable] AS P
              WHERE [MyTable].[Parent] = P.[Child]
                AND [P].[MyLevel] = 6);
```

We were hoping for some SQLite experts advice on a better performing update query.

Comment: Show the table/index definitions.

Comment: RecNo IndexName IndexFieldsDisplay Unique Where
1 pmxWBS_ProjDefWBSID SourceFile, ProjDefWBSID FALSE 
2 pmxWBS_Parent SourceFile, Parent FALSE 
3 pmxWBS_WBSLevel WBSLevel FALSE 
4 pmxWBS_WBSID WBSID FALSE 
ProjDefWBSID represents "Child" and pmxWBS represents MyTable

Comment: this morning we changed the index "pxmWBS_ProjDefWBSID" (in the example this is "child") which consists of two fields ([SourceFile], [ProjDefWBSID]) to UNIQUE. This appears to have made a big difference!